# How to calculate "Concurrent_reads" parameter in cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra

How to calculate  and set the "concurrent_read" parameter in cassandra.yaml file in cassandra DB.
It shows "cassandra_read" is calculated as 16*num of drives.
My question is ,what exactly this "num of drives" is and how to calculate it??
Assuming system has 8 cores, 32 GB RAM and 1TB of hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

One way to configure Apache Cassandra's data directories, was to use multiple data drives.  In the bare metal world of a few years ago, this was usually multiple, physical disks.  The way to configure them in the `cassandra.yaml` would be like this:

```
data_file_directories:
    - /data01
    - /data02
    - /data03
    - /data04
```

This assumes that the Cassandra instance has four physical drives, attached on the data0[1-4] mount points.  Cassandra would then treat these directories in a JBOD (just a bunch of disks) fashion, spreading data evenly across them.

In this case, computing `concurrent_reads` with your formula above would be 16 x 4, as there are four drives.  Given the emergence of solid state drives, the use of multiple, physical (or logical) disks isn't done much today (in my experience).

**tl;dr;**

If you're unsure of how many drives you have, check your mount points (`df -h`, `/etc/fstab`, etc...).  Or you will probably be fine assuming one, and adjusting that calculation based on your available compute resources.